# CGRectのエラーについて

Tags: swift, ios, iphone, swift3

swift3に変わってからCGRectの書き方が変更になったのは知っていたのですが、少し昔のサイトhttp://qiita.com/okmr-d/items/07731aa1ede2998d823d を参考にして書いたので、エラーが出てしまいました。

LaunchScreenをアニメーションさせようとしてます。

直し方を教えていただけると幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: コードを掲載する場合は、可能な限り **本文内にテキストとして** 含めるようにしてください。またビルド時にデバッグコンソール部分に表示される **エラーメッセージ** も重要な情報ですのでそちらも本文中に含めるようにしてください。画像も補助的な情報としては有用ですが、画像だけですとエラーを再現したりエラーメッセージを読み取ることが大変なため、回答者の負担を増やしますし、テキスト検索ではヒットしないため、今後このサイトを訪れる方々にとっての情報としても役に立ちにくくなってしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'init(CGRect:)' has been replaced by 'init(cgRect:)'

とあるように、NSValue(CGRect: r) ではなく NSValue(cgRect: r) です。